# When handling file upload with PHP is the data loaded into memory?

Tags: php

When using the ubiquitous file upload paradigm in PHP, example:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Is the file itself loaded into memory or is the $_FILES global used as a reference to the file?

If the file is not loaded into memory, what is the purpose of this line from the PHP doc regarding file upload pitfalls:

**If a memory limit is enabled, a larger memory_limit may be needed. Make sure you set memory_limit large enough.**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not loaded into memory -- that would be a genuine pessimization. You can load the contents into memory in the manner of your choice by reading from `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the file upload itself is handled by the web server. Of course the web server needs to reserve some memory for the upload, but it's only as much as the read/write buffer size is large. Guess somewhat like 4096 Bytes.

After they file is uploaded, the web server populates the temporary name of the uploaded file(s) and some others information about it to php and php is making this information available in `$_FILES`, but it will not have the uploaded file in memory.

Comment: Can you point to any doc that describes this in detail? I've been looking on php.net and haven't been able to really get a good detailed description of what is actually going on.

Comment: while you can trust me, I will have a look for some more documentation

Comment: My own intuition says that it is not loaded into memory, but if you check my edit - the bold text - has me wondering.

Comment: Sounds for me like a documentation pitfall :) .. They say *may*, not *will*

Comment: Lol, it's not too precise. You may need larger memory_limit... at what point? lol

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with the file. If you are reading it into a PHP variable you will possibly need more memory..